# Modify All varchar elements in a MySQL column

Tags: mysql

In a MySQL database,
I have a table `License` with a few example rows as presented below:

```
ID  |   Key     |   Location
1       25          C:/Public/lics/1885-0001.lic
3       21          C:/Public/lics/1885-0006.lic
```

There are many such rows, which I would like to modify as given below:

```
ID  |   Key     |   Location
1       25          C:/Licenses/1885-0001.lic
3       21          C:/Licenses/1885-0006.lic
```

One of the columns from all the rows get modified. How do I update the table to make this change across all rows.

Comment: Check the REPLACE function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the docs I posted in my comment, I think you should do something like this:

```
UPDATE License SET Location = REPLACE(Location, 'C:/Public/lics', 'C:/Licenses');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   UPDATE License
   SET Value = REPLACE(Location, 'Public/lics', 'Licenses')
```